# Rails tolk import directory tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I decided to try out tolk to better manage my translations. The problem is that currently my locale strings are spread across multiple files in the /locales directory and I cannot find a way to import them all. Interesting enough

```
rake tolk:sync
```

managed to fetch all my base locale string, but

```
rake tolk:import
```

could not import the other locales except those in the **.yml files in the root dir.